# Show selected items in a multi-select list box

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have tried various ways to get this to work. I think maybe I have something missing in my model or controller, so I'm posting all three parts.

I have data in a database that shows some advising topics chosen by an advisor in a previous appointment. When the advisor calls up that appointment, the app should display a list of all possible topics with the ones previously chosen highlighted. Everything works except that last bit.

I know I'm retrieving the right information because I can display the selected items separately. I just can't get them to show up selected. Here's the code. I'm cutting out irrelevant parts.

```
public class AppointmentModel
{ ...
    public string AdvisingTopicId { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> AdvisingIdList { get; set; }
    public SelectList AdvisingTopicNames { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : AdvisorBaseController
{ ...
        var topicCodes = appointment.advising_topic.ToList();

        var advisingTopics = new SelectList((from t in topicCodes
                              select t.name).ToList(), "name");

        var topicsList = (from t in db.advising_topic
                          select new SelectListItem
                          {
                              Selected = false,
                              Text = t.name,
                              Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)t.advising_topic_id).Trim()
                          }).ToList();

        foreach (var topicCode in topicCodes)
        {
            var selTopic = topicsList.Find(x => x.Value == topicCode.advising_topic_id.ToString());
            if (selTopic != null)
            {
                selTopic.Selected = true;
            }
        } ...
            var appointmentModel = new AppointmentModel
            { ...
                AdvisingTopicNames = advisingTopics,
                AdvisingIdList = topicsList,
            };
```

and then the view

```
@model AcademicAdvising.Models.AppointmentModel
<h3>Advising Topics</h3>
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model.AdvisingTopicNames)
    {
        <li>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item)</li>
    }
</ul>
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m=>m.AdvisingIdList, new SelectList(Model.AdvisingTopicNames, "Value", "Text", Model.AdvisingTopicNames.SelectedValue))
```

Note that the foreach correctly displays the selected items. That's just for testing and will be pulled out. the ListBoxFor is where I'm struggling. What I have here doesn't work (shows the full list with nothing highlighted). And that's the bit where I have tried various approaches, with all fails.

Comment: Bryan Roberts' suggestion works. That is
@Html.ListBox("myLB", Model.AdvisingIdList)
returns the list highlighted. So I'm going to mark this as Answered and go away and try to figure out why it doesn't work with ListBoxFor

Comment: There can sometimes be naming problems.  Look at the names you are defining and make sure you are not reusing them.  Pay attention to query string parameters and items that are being put into the viewbag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may have accidentely went a level too deep.  You already have a select list which is all the listboxfor function wants.

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(m=>m.AdvisingIdList, Model.AdvisingTopicNames)
```

But honestly looking at how you are defining your lists I think what you really want might be

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(m=>m.AdvisingIdList, Model.AdvisingIdList)
```

Comment: Neither of those worked. The former causes only the selected topics to display (with nothing highlighted). The latter causes all the topics to display, but with nothing highlighted. Thanks for the quick reply, though.

Comment: That sounds like a data problem.  The second one is showing the full list but what is happening sounds like you aren't setting anything to 'selected' check out your line of code if (selTopic != null)
            {
                selTopic.Selected = true;
            }  And make sure that if is actually being hit and something is triggering the selected flag to true.

Comment: I thought I had checked that, but I'll look again because your thought is much like mine -- it just felt like a data problem not a presentation problem. If I can get this fixed, I'll be back to mark the solution.

Comment: Well, fiddle. From the controller, it's definitely being it. topicsList contains all topics and debug shows that some are set to Selected=True while others are set to False. They're even the right ones! :)
     
That means that the field called AdvisingIdList contains all 22 topics, with Selected set to True on some of them. That's exactly what I want. Now it seems I'm back to a presentation problem!

Comment: And you are using @Html.ListBoxFor(m=>m.AdvisingIdList, Model.AdvisingIdList) now right?

Comment: @Html.ListBoxFor(m=>m.AdvisingIdList, Model.AdvisingIdList)

That's correct. I just re-ran it from Visual Studio. Same result: I get all the topics with none highlighted to show they have been previously selected.

Comment: I have a basic example of this working.  It may be some kind of problem with things being named the same.  Try just using a regular List box @Html.ListBox("myLB", Model.AdvisingIdList)